# c# drag and drop href image from webbrowser

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, webbrowser-control

I've tried with my code my source code

```
e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat).ToString();
```

or

```
e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
```

But I only gets redirect url. i want to get image url not a redirect url(a href).

How can I get the image url?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with Internet Explorer. However, in Chrome/FF you should be able to use

```
e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Html).ToString();
```

This will give you the HTML markup of the image tag, which you could then use RegEx or manually parse the link yourself.

Edit: Here is the code I used to test.

```
For Each s As String In e.Data.GetFormats()
    If (e.Data.GetData(s) IsNot Nothing) Then
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data.GetData(s).ToString())
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Then is it any way for drag and drop image from IE?

Comment: I don't think so. I tested on IE 8, so maybe a later version would support it. This is a browser issue though, not a code issue. You can try it with other browsers and see if it works. See my edit above for the code I used to test.